# How to retrieve table data from local storage in the correct format?

Tags: javascript

I'm building an expense tracker app that saves data entered into a form, then registered into a table under(Name, Date and Amount) inputs, it then saves that data in the browser's local storage as an array. I am trying to retrieve the table data as it was registered into the table(in the correct rows and columns) when the page is reloaded.

```
//FUNCTION TO GET EXISTING EXPENSES FROM LOCAL STORAGE WHEN PAGE IS REFRESHED (display Table on the screen with refreshing Page)
function getExpenses(expenses) {
  //CHECK If an expense exists in Local Storage
  //Checks if expense exists

  if (localStorage.getItem("expenses") === null) {
    expenses = []; //create a new array for expenses if none exists
  } else {
    expenses = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("expenses")); //Gets back the array of existing expenses if expenses exist
  }

  expenses.forEach((item) => {

    //create <tr></tr>
    const tableRow = document.createElement("tr"); //new table row
    tableRow.classList.add("table-row"); //set class to t-row
    tableHead.appendChild(tableRow); //Append new row(.tableHead) to the table in HTML

    //create <td></td>
    const tableDataA = document.createElement("td"); //New Table Data Element
    tableDataA.innerText = item;
    tableRow.appendChild(tableDataA);

    const tableDataB = document.createElement("td");
    tableDataB.innerText = item;
    tableRow.appendChild(tableDataB);

    const tableDataC = document.createElement("td");
    tableDataC.innerText = item;
    tableRow.appendChild(tableDataC);

    //APPEND 
    expenseTable.appendChild(tableRow); //To Append .t-row to the Table element in our HTML file

  });

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a bit more info? e.g. what error are you seeing? and what does the code look like that defines the global `expenseTable` variable and when/where does `getExpenses(expenses)` get called? and what is passed in? (it looks like it gets overridden immediately)

Comment: `tableDataA.innerText = item;` should be setting the text to one of the properties of the item, not the whole item.

Comment: Like `item.name`

Comment: But based on the output you show, it looks `expenses` is an array of strings. It should be an array of objects.

Comment: So basically when I enter data into table from the form and reload the page, the data that is retrieved from local storage is entered wrongly into the table e.g date and amount data entered into name column. And the global expenseTable is a querySelector for the Table element in the HTML. https://codepen.io/322slimey/pen/wvPzaqa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output you're getting, `expenses` is an array of strings rather than an array of objects. So you need to iterate over it in groups of 3, putting sequential elements from each group into a different TD.

You can't do this easily with `forEach()`, so use a `for` loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < expenses.length; i += 3) {
  //create <tr></tr>
  const tableRow = document.createElement("tr"); //new table row
  tableRow.classList.add("table-row"); //set class to t-row
  tableHead.appendChild(tableRow); //Append new row(.tableHead) to the table in HTML

  //create <td></td>
  const tableDataA = document.createElement("td"); //New Table Data Element
  tableDataA.innerText = expenses[i];
  tableRow.appendChild(tableDataA);

  const tableDataB = document.createElement("td");
  tableDataB.innerText = expenses[i + 1];
  tableRow.appendChild(tableDataB);

  const tableDataC = document.createElement("td");
  tableDataC.innerText = expenses[i + 2];
  tableRow.appendChild(tableDataC);

  //APPEND 
  expenseTable.appendChild(tableRow); //To Append .t-row to the Table element in our HTML file
}
```

It would probably be better if you redesigned your `expenses` array to be an array of objects rather than separate elements for each column, e.g.

```
[
    {
        name: "Gym",
        date: "2022-02-15",
        amount: 200
    },
    {
        name: "Grocery",
        date: "2022-02-20",
        amount: 500
    }
]
```